# DLL Exporting Abstract Base Class as Argument to Member Function - C++

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how I go about exporting a DLL (with `__declspec(dllexport)` - so, Windows, using MSVC) with a member function that has an abstract base class (smart pointer to-) as an argument.

Currently, I'm getting error C2280: `std::unique_ptr<Base>...` attempting to reference a deleted function.  Here's an example:

**DLL:**

class.h

```
#ifdef DLLFILE //defined in MSVC for compiling DLL, not defined for exe
#define DLLEXP __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLEXP __declspec(dllimport)
#endif /* DLLFILE */

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
class DLLEXP Base
{ //Base class that provides a pure virtual interface to a function that could have a variety of implementations
public:
    virtual double fieldAtS(double s) = 0;
};

class DLLEXP Derived : public Base
{ //Some derived implementation of Base
private:
    std::function<double(double)> fcn_m;

public:
    Derived(std::function<double(double)> fcn);
    double fieldAtS(double s) override;
};

class DLLEXP Container
{ //Container class that stores implementations of Derived and determines the sum of all implementations
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> elems_m;

public:
    void add(std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr);
    double fieldAtS(double s);
};
```

class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
Derived::Derived(std::function<double(double)> fcn) : fcn_m{ fcn }
{

}

double Derived::fieldAtS(double s)
{
    return fcn_m(s);
}

void Container::add(std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr)
{
    elems_m.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}

double Container::fieldAtS(double s)
{
    double ret{ 0.0 };
    for (auto& der : elems_m)
        ret += der->fieldAtS(s);

    return ret;
}
```

**EXE:**

main.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Container> mine{ std::make_unique<Container>() };

    mine->add(std::make_unique<Derived>([](double x) { return 10.0 * x; }));
    mine->add(std::make_unique<Derived>([](double x) { return x; }));
    mine->add(std::make_unique<Derived>([](double x) { return x / 10.0; }));

    std::cout << mine->fieldAtS(5.0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think I get what is happening here (check my understanding)...namely, the compiler is compiling `Container::add(unique_ptr<Base>)` and because dllexport is specified, a byte-code version of `unique_ptr<Base>` has to be included in the DLL (instead of relying on it being created at runtime - is this what happens?), which the compiler is unable to do because of the pure virtual function in `Base`.  Am I on the right track?

My goals are:

1. Achieve polymorphism for `fieldAtS` - that is, there are a few field models that I want to be able to choose from at runtime (and when appropriate, add multiple to `Container` / sum them to get the total field from all elements contributing)
2. Export these classes from the DLL and call them somewhere else
3. Still use smart pointers (in other places in my code, I have exported functions that dynamically create an instance of a class and pass a (dumb) pointer out, as well as, in other cases take in the dumb pointer and call member functions on it - wanting to avoid this).

So a few questions:

- Is my understanding about what is happening right?
- Is this a good design methodology for a class that has to be (maybe doesn't have to be) `dllexport` 'ed?
- How would I go about achieving my goals here?  That is, if this is good design, how do I properly export the container?  If not, how else should I structure my code?

**EDIT: Build Log/Updated Info**

It seems as if the error refers to a default copy constructor: `Base& Base::operator=(const Base&) = delete;` ... so, I have to explicitly declare a copy constructor if I'm `dllexport` 'ing?

Build log is below:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: DLL, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  dllmain.cpp
1>%BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(18): warning C4251: 'Derived::fcn_m': class 'std::function<double (double)>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Derived'
1>  %BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(18): note: see declaration of 'std::function<double (double)>'
1>%BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(28): warning C4251: 'Container::elems_m': class 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Container'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Base
1>          ]
1>  %BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(28): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Base
1>          ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2316): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Base
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\memory(1436): note: see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Base
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2335): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_unchecked1<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::_General_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *,
1>              _InIt=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(997): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt *std::_Copy_unchecked<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>*,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *,
1>              _Ty=Base,
1>              _InIt=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> *
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(980): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::operator =(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Base
1>          ]
1>  %BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(33): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::operator =(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Base
1>          ]
1>  %BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(28): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Base
1>          ]
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ClassExport, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>  main.cpp
2>%BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(18): warning C4251: 'Derived::fcn_m': class 'std::function<double (double)>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Derived'
2>  %BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(18): note: see declaration of 'std::function<double (double)>'
2>%BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(28): warning C4251: 'Container::elems_m': class 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Container'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=Base
2>          ]
2>  %BASEFOLDER%\include\class.h(28): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=Base
2>          ]
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'class.lib'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please post complete build log here.

Comment: @VTT Posted.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that my explanation is correct, but I believe the reason is different. Observe that the problem is when you are exporting the class, not importing it. If you remove the dllexport, everything will go fine, but you will get linker problems.

The reason is that you told the compiler to export all the class functions, and that apparently includes the default ones (default constructor, default copy constructor etc.). The problem here is with `operator=` and the copy constructor, since they can not exist for your class, because `std::unique_ptr<Base>` is not copyable. The solution is to delete them, like so:

```
class DLLEXP Container
{
public:
    Container();
    Container(const Container&) = delete;
    Container& operator=(const Container&) = delete;
}
```

In normal code (no DLLs), you would get the same problem as soon as you would try to use the copy constructor. But in this case, you get the errors early.

Also note that:

- The compiler warns you that all the memebers etc. should by dllexported, only ignore this if you know what you are doing
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 describes the import/export behavior for classes
- Exporting templates and STL classes is hell to get right and should be avoided, on older VS version you could expect really subtle run-time bugs
- If nothing has changed, there is no byte-code for templates in DLL. You either have to export templates specialized for a concrete type using dllexport, or provide full headers including implementation.

Comment: "The compiler warns you that all mem..." Can you explain this a bit more?  I'm getting an error C4251 - `somefunc` needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'someclass'...is this related to what you are saying?  For exporting STL stuff, I've seen that advice around...for me I'm compiling everything with one compiler (tests are the only thing accessing the classes directly)...and have heard that as long as the same compiler is used, it's generally not an issue.  Do you concur?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that warning -- the compiler warns you about future problems you might get with, for example, inherited classes. As to the STL problem, I am not aware of the current state (you will have to look it up), but it was problem even when using the same compiler. The basic problem is that if you use templated classes from two modules (let's say DLL and EXE), they will have separate static data.

Comment: So what could I do about the warning?  How would I provide a dll interface in a way that satisfies the warning?  I'll search around for the STL problem.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not really sure how to do that simply and still use STL containers (which is ok in this case, because they are not leaving the class). One solution is to use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl , but I understand if you don't want to do that.

Comment: Depending on how "heavy" the Container is, you might provide a complete inline implementation in the header, as if it was a template (no DLLEXPORT). And you also CAN ignore the warning :) .

Comment: For my use case...I think templates are out.  The classes are too big (also sometimes CUDA-enabled)...and yes, I'd prefer not to use pimpl.  I suppose I only need classes exported for testing...I can run my tests to make sure the code is working and after, remove the export.  That's probably what I'll do.  Thanks again!